# How to set the data in Redux when I am fetching something?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Good evening,

I am making weather app with react and redux. I have my reducer with a object of my data info with empty string etc:

```html
const initState = {
  city: '',
  temp: '',
  wind: ''
}
```

And for example in React I am gonna fetch all the data and what should i do now?
I should have dispatch action (FILL DATA - for example) and then i should make a [useState] inside my component for temporary place for my data. Then fill the data in my temporary place and then useDispatch to update redux store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are a few ways to do this, such as:

- Use a redux middleware like `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk`, which I recommend.
- In the request action, make the asynchronous call and then dispatch the success action to update the state data.
- Call the API from the component and call the state redux store update action to update the global state. NOT RECOMMENDED.

Apparently, you're trying to use the third way, but it's not recommended because it beats the purpose of abstract redux and making the data scattered all around. A bad practice.

A middleware example would be very long, so I'll try to explain the second way briefly.

In your request action, do something like this:

```
...
axios.get(url).then(res => {
  dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_SUCCESS', data: res.data });
});
```

In your reducer:

```
...
switch (action.type) {
  case: 'REQUEST_SUCCESS';
    return { ...state, ...action.data };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) that will help you with this. It allows actions to be asynchronous, so you can actually dispatch the action, fetch all the data INSIDE the action and then dispatch an action to fill your state. After configuring it, your action would look something like this:

```
const getWeatherData = () => { // Declare it like any other action
  return async (dispatch) => { //Then return a promise
    const response = await getWeatherAPI(); // fetch from the backend
    return dispatch({  // And then dispatch another action to populate your reducer
       type: "FILL_DATA",
       payload: response
    })

  }

}
```

This action would be dispatched from your code just like any other action, but considering it returns a promise you can actually await for it to finish and handle that any way you want.